# Changing items within custom UITableViewCell Class

Tags: swift, uitableview

I have 2 classes - a UITableViewController and a custom UITableViewCell. I want to change the cell height for my UITableViewController, so I implement the following:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return tableView.frame.height*(1/12)
}
```

and it works! The cell height changes. Now, I go into my custom UITableViewCell class

```
import UIKit

class TableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    var time:UILabel = UILabel()
    var name:UILabel = UILabel()

    override init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier) // the common code is executed in this super call

        let imageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.frame.width*0.22, height: self.frame.height))
        imageView.image = UIImage(named: "Person")
        imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
        imageView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        self.addSubview(imageView)

        let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(signIn))
        imageView.addGestureRecognizer(tap)

        name = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: self.frame.width*0.22, y: 0, width: self.frame.width*0.78, height: self.frame.height*0.7))
        name.textColor = UIColor.gray
        name.font = UIFont(name: name.font!.fontName, size: 30)
        name.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
        self.addSubview(name)

        time = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: self.frame.width*0.22, y: self.frame.height*0.65, width: self.frame.width*0.78, height: self.frame.height*0.3))
        time.textColor = UIColor.gray
        time.font = UIFont(name: time.font!.fontName, size: 15)
        time.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
        self.addSubview(time)
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code
    }

    @objc func signIn(tap: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
        let tappedImage = tap.view as! UIImageView
        tappedImage.image = UIImage(named: "PersonClocked")
    }

    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

        // Configure the view for the selected state
    }

}
```

So, I now edit the function inside my controller to call the cells.

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell { 
    let cell:TableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! TableViewCell

    cell.layer.borderColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
    cell.layer.borderWidth = 1

    cell.name.text = names[indexPath.row]
    cell.time.text = times[indexPath.row]

    return cell
}
```

I expect it to all work now! But, it doesn't. For whatever reason, the methods get called in this order...

```
tableview(cellForRowAt) -> TableViewCell(override init) -> tableView(heightForRowAt)'
```

So, when I go to run it, it looks something like below. The cell is created with Swift's/Apple's default runtime tableView, then the cell size is changed, but everything inside the cell is still the size of the original default value. I need it to be the size of the cell. Any ideas? 
Note - I added a border so you could see the size of the cell compared to the items.[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Frame layout can't help in creating dynamic height tables you have to use dynamic tableViewCells and create the cell's contentView with constraints to get the height change with the current content

//

```
override init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
    super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier) // the common code is executed in this super call

    let imageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.frame.width*0.22, height: self.frame.height))
    imageView.image = UIImage(named: "Person")
    imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
    imageView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    self.addSubview(imageView)

    let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(signIn))
    imageView.addGestureRecognizer(tap)

    name = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: self.frame.width*0.22, y: 0, width: self.frame.width*0.78, height: self.frame.height*0.7))
    name.textColor = UIColor.gray
    name.font = UIFont(name: name.font!.fontName, size: 30)
    name.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
    self.addSubview(name)

    time = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: self.frame.width*0.22, y: self.frame.height*0.65, width: self.frame.width*0.78, height: self.frame.height*0.3))
    time.textColor = UIColor.gray
    time.font = UIFont(name: time.font!.fontName, size: 15)
    time.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
    self.addSubview(time)

    imageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    name.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    time.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

    imageView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.centerYAnchor,constant: 0).isActive = true
    imageView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.leadingAnchor,constant: 20).isActive = true
    imageView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 30).isActive = true
    imageView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 30).isActive = true

    name.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.topAnchor,constant: 20).isActive = true
    name.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: imageView.leadingAnchor,constant: 20).isActive = true
    name.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.trailingAnchor,constant: -20).isActive = true

    time.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: name.topAnchor,constant: 20).isActive = true
    time.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: imageView.leadingAnchor,constant: 20).isActive = true
    time.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.trailingAnchor,constant: -20).isActive = true
    time.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.bottomAnchor,constant: -20).isActive = true

}
```

//

put this in `viewDidLoad`

```
 tableview.estimatedRowHeight = 100 
 tableview.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
```

and don't implement `heightForRowAt` method

Comment: With slight modifications this worked the way I needed it to. Didn't need automatic dimension, but contraining to the edges was what I was looking for! thanks!